# wifi connected but no internet, is this the end?

Tags: 12.10, wireless

this is my story:
I left my laptop at home connected to the router and with teamviewer on. Remotely I was controlling it about 2 hours, at a specific moment the connection has disapeared. When I came back, the laptop was on and still connected to the router but no internet connection.

1. The router is fine, if I connect another device it works.
2. I still can see other wifi networks and try to connect to them.
3. I was not installing anything new software on it while controlling it remotely.
4. Nobody touched it.
5. It was not a power failure, everything was like I left it.
6. Tried with a life cd, same situation
7. Ubuntu 12.10 on Acer Aspire 7730

ifconfig:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:ea:a4:17:52  
          inet addr:192.168.1.109  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:eaff:fea4:1752/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4910 (4.9 KB)  TX bytes:13172 (13.1 KB)
```

iwconfig:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Real+"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: 00:18:E7:FA:7F:5F   
          Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:35   Missed beacon:0
```

route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

ping -c4 173.194.70.113:

```
PING 173.194.70.113 (173.194.70.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 173.194.70.113 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3023ms
```

Interesting the default gateway ping works, ping 192.168.1.1:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=3.05 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=6.23 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.051/4.644/6.237/1.593 ms
```

lspci -nn | grep 0280:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
```

Is this a bad new and I have to buy a new wifi card?

Comment: How do you know there is no internet connection? The outputs you posted look ok. Try pinging Google like this `ping -c4 173.194.70.113`.

Comment: Only the default gateway (192.168.1.1) get pinged, i will add it to the question

Comment: Is this by chance an Intel card? lspci -nn | grep 0280  We may need to disable 802.11N.

Comment: @chili555, yes, `07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]`, the laptops is 4 years old and the card has draft N

Comment: can you try my answer from this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278694/wifi-connects-but-pages-dont-load/1281120#comment2173899_1281120

Comment: sorry to inform you, but I asked this question 7 years ago :D
I solved the issue just by reinstalling the system

Comment: @micnic Oh , *facepalm* Thank gosh it was solved anyway, haha - Okay, Have a great continuing day,  sir!  Regards,  Will.

Comment: @WilliamMartens no problem, thanks for helping with this kind of issues, have a nice day too!

Answer (score 2):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

A new, empty file will open. Add one line:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: Ideally, it solves the 'connected to the router but no internet' problem. It's a pretty well known bug. If, however, it doesn't help, it's easy enough to simply delete the conf file and troubleshoot further.

Comment: unfortunately, this did not help :( waiting for a miracle, are there any other solutions?

Comment: Are your symptoms the same? Any clues here? dmesg | grep -e wlan -e iwl or here? nm-tool